# PrimeFaces: Keep upload running in case of server restart?

Tags: primefaces, tomcat7, jsf-2.2

My applications handle large file uploads (more than 1GB), and if need to restart the server the upload is process is aborted.

I'm using PF 4.0.13 + Commons FileUpload 1.3.1 with threshold size of 1 MB. Temporary files are kept on server restart.

Probably I'm asking for too much, but is there a way to make the fileUpload component keep retrying in case of connection is lost?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using Amazon S3, I changed my code to use the AWS SDK for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that is not supported with Apache Commons FileUpload.

Comment: What about Tomcat's native upload? Thanks

Comment: The Servlet 3.0 file upload is just a copy of Commons FileUpload. The closest you can get to this with Tomcat out of the box features is using partial PUTs and the default servlet but that will require custom client code (and enabling PUTs). I think you need to be looking for an alternative upload library.